# Trying to catch data from req.body it brings me an empty object?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

I try to catch data from Postman but "req.body" brings out an empty object for me. What can be a problem with that?

I am not that good at Node.js and Express.

I read many questions on StackOverFlow but nothing worked for me, neither session nor anything else.

I've got a file app:

```
/*********
* app.js file
*********/


const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function () {
  let server = express(),
    create,
    start;

  create = (config, db) => {
    // add middleware to parse the json
    server.use(bodyParser.json());
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    }));

    let routes = require('../routes');
    // set all the server things
    server.set('env', config.env);
    server.set('port', config.port);
    server.set('hostname', config.hostname);


    //connect the database
    mongoose.connect(
      db.database,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
      }
    );

    // Set up routes
    routes.init(server);
  };


  start = () => {
    let hostname = server.get('hostname'),
      port = server.get('port');
    server.listen(port, function () {
      console.log('Express server listening on - http://' + hostname + ':' + port);
    });
  };
  return {
    create: create,
    start: start
  };
};
```

Here below when I try to catch data it's empty (undefined)

my user.js service

```
/********
* user.js file (services/users)
********/


const express = require('express');
const User = require('../../models/user');

const getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    let users = await User.find({});

    if (users.length > 0) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        'message': 'users fetched successfully',
        'data': users
      });
    }

    return res.status(404).json({
      'code': 'BAD_REQUEST_ERROR',
      'description': 'No users found in the system'
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      'code': 'SERVER_ERROR',
      'description': 'something went wrong, Please try again'
    });
  }
}

const createUser = async (req, res, next) => {

  try {

    const {
      name,
      email
    } = req.body;

    if (name === undefined || name === '') {
      return res.status(422).json({
        'code': 'REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING',
        'description': 'name is required',
        'field': 'name'
      });
    }

    if (email === undefined || email === '') {
      return res.status(422).json({
        'code': 'REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING',
        'description': 'email is required',
        'field': 'email'
      });
    }


    let isEmailExists = await User.findOne({
      "email": email
    });

    if (isEmailExists) {
      return res.status(409).json({
        'code': 'ENTITY_ALREADY_EXISTS',
        'description': 'email already exists',
        'field': 'email'
      });
    }

    const temp = {
      name: name,
      email: email
    }

    let newUser = await User.create(temp);

    if (newUser) {
      return res.status(201).json({
        'message': 'user created successfully',
        'data': newUser
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error('something went worng');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      'code': 'SERVER_ERROR',
      'description': 'something went wrong, Please try again'
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getUsers: getUsers,
  getUserById: getUserById,
  createUser: createUser,
  updateUser: updateUser,
  deleteUser: deleteUser
}
```

I would appreciate any hints and suggestions on the code

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `req.body` field will be an empty object if nothing is sent in the body. For any `GET` requests, if you send data to the endpoint you would send via params (i.e, `[website].com?paramkey1=paramvalue1&paramkey2=paramvalue2`), and the body will always be an empty object. For `POST` and `PUT` requests you will send data in the body and `req.body` should contain that data.

I assume you are testing the createUser function. First off, I would try console logging `req.body` at the top of the `createUser` functions in case the field names are incorrect. Also, the Postman sections where you add the Body and where you add the Params look almost identical, so you may want to try console logging `req.query` too and/or confirm you're in the right spot on Postman.

Hard to know without more info. You know the routes are being setup, correct? Are you getting a successful response in Postman?